# Need a buffer class for NumPy ndarray data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, queue, containers

I need a good buffer for numpy `ndarray` data. I need to push there some arrays, the queue should somehow concatenate them into one, and then I want to get arbitrary length arrays out of it.

Something like this:

```
# push some numpy arrays into buffer
buffer.push(in_array_1)
buffer.push(in_array_2)
buffer.push(in_array_3)

# return a new numpy array with arbitrary length num_of_elements_to_get
out_array = buffer.get(num_of_elements_to_get)
```

Cannot you advice me something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy and the `ndarray` can do what you describe, without any additional classes:

- To push arrays to the buffer, concatene them to the array
- To get elements from the buffer, access the slice (and then delete it, if that's what you want)

If that is good enough for you depends on what you expect of a "good buffer"...

It can work like this:

```
buffer = np.array([])

# I assume the arrays are one-dimensional.
buffer = np.concatenate([buffer, in_array_1])
buffer = np.concatenate([buffer, in_array_2])
buffer = np.concatenate([buffer, in_array_3])

out_array = buffer[:num_of_elements_to_get]
buffer = np.delete(buffer, slice(0, num_of_elements_to_get))  # remove elements (optional)
```

If you want to hide the details, you can create a class that stores `buffer` in an attribute and implement `push` and `pop` or `get` methods. Don't forget error checking in the getter (`num_of_elements_to_get <= buffer.size`). I would call the method `get` if it only returns elements, and `pop` if it removes elements.

---

As hpaulj pointed out, it is possible combine multiple concatenations in one function call:

```
buffer = np.concatenate([buffer, in_array_1, in_array_2, in_array_3])
```

This causes less re-allocations of the buffer. However, if allocations are an issue it may be better to invest a bit more effort and implement a ring buffer.

As an additional note, a setter method can be designed to take multiple arrays:

```
def push(self, *args):
    self.buffer = np.concatenate([self.buffer] + args)
```

Comment: But `buffer = np.concatenate([in_array_1, in_array_2, in_array_3])` would be better `numpy` code.  It just doesn't look like the `buffer.push...` model.

Comment: @hpaulj True. I undestood that as examples oft three independent pushes, but if more inputs are available at the same time your comment makes sense.